# Dapper Query return always null with nullable immutable struct

Tags: c#, dapper

With Dapper 2.0.123, SQL Server 2019, .NET6 :

**Working**

I can use an immutable struct like this :

```
// Immutable struct
public struct UserImmutable
{
    public UserImmutable(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        this.LastName = lastName;
        this.FirstName = firstName;
    }
    public string LastName { get; }
    public string FirstName { get; }
}

// Dapper code
var result = connection.Query<UserImmutable>("SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM [User];").ToList();
```

The result is filled correctly with all values.

**Not Working**

Now if I change the generic type for **`UserImmutable?`** when calling `Query`, I have the same number of items, but they are all NULL, even if the the SQL query returns no NULL

```
var result = connection.Query<UserImmutable?>("SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM [User];").ToList();
// result[0] is null, result[1] is null, etc.
```

What I am missing ?

Comment: My guess is that a nullable type has no constructor, and since you don't have any setters, the could be that nothing is created in that case. Try making a parameterless constructor with public setters. If that works you know it is related to that.

Comment: `UserImmutable?` has two properties: `bool HasValue` and `UserImmutable Value`, neither of which are in your resultset. Why do you want `UserImmutable?` in the first place?

Comment: Joost00719 and @Charlieface, Dapper can automatically use a constructor when parameters match resultset, that's why it works whith the non nullable immutable struct. I want to use a nullable struct to get a list of position LatLng (immutable struct), but the position can also be null. Indeed, I didn't think that Dapper should probably detect the Value and HasValue properties regardless of the underlying type, and thus not use FirstName and LastName in the example. I can use an intermediate class, but I wanted to understand the reason behind.

Comment: If you have rows with nulls then you will get a struct which has `LastName = null` and `FirstName = null` anyway, because `string` can be null, so why would you need to make the whole thing itself nullable? Note that `default(UserImmutable)` is the same as that anyway. At the end of the day, Dapper expects the `T` generic parameter to map to the whole row, it's only if you have individual properties/column that a nullable makes sense.